# Javascript/CSS slideshow background back to selected on hover out

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, hover, slideshow

I've programmed a slideshow on this Wordpress site www.2eenheid.de. 
When you hover over the menu in the slideshow e.g. Support / Beheer, Implementatie or Cloud it will show a different background image. When you click on a menu item the background changes too and it stays on that image EXCEPT when you hover again over a menu item, it then stays on the image that you last hovered on.

It's supposed to do this:

1. User selects menu item and it changes background image
2. When clicked on menu item it stays the same background image
3. When user hover over another menu item it goes to a different image
4. On hover OUT the background image changes back to the image of the selected page.

This is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/script/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
     $('ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').fadeTo('slow', 1);
     $('ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').hover(function(){
      $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
      $('.pikachoose').css({ 'background-image' : 'url('+$(this).attr('src')+')' });
     }, function(){
      $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
     });
    });
    </script>
```

The HTML:

```
            <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="pika-wrapper">
                    <div class="pikachoose <?php if (is_page('cloud')) { echo "cloudclass"; }?><?php if (is_page('implementatie')) { echo "implementatieclass"; }?><?php if (is_page('webhosting-en-hosting')) { echo "hostingclass"; }?><?php if (is_page('unit4-multivers')) { echo "unitclass"; }?><?php if (is_page('over-2eenheid')) { echo "overclass"; }?><?php if (is_page('algemene-voorwaarden')) { echo "voorwaardenclass"; }?><?php if (is_page('vacature')) { echo "vacatureclass"; }?><?php if (is_page('contact')) { echo "contactclass"; }?><?php if (is_page('supportenbeheer')) { echo "supportclass"; }?><?php if (is_page('home')) { echo "homeclass"; }?><?php if (is_page('testimonials')) { echo "testimonialsclass"; }?>">
                    <ul id="pikame" class="jcarousel-skin-pika">

                    </ul>
            </div>          

            <div class="slideshow-menu-wrapper">
            <div class="support-button"><a href="http://www.2eenheid.nl/tmv/tmv.exe" title="Remote support"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/supportbutton.png" /></a></div><!-- supportbutton -->
            <div id="slideshow-main">
                    <ul class="slideshow-menu">
                        <li class="<?php if (is_page('supportenbeheer')) { echo "current_page_item"; }?>"><a title="Support / Beheer" href="/supportenbeheer" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-4.jpg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-4.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Support / Beheer</span></a></li>
                        <li class="<?php if (is_page('implementatie')) { echo "current_page_item"; }?>"><a href="/implementatie" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-5.jpg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-5.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Implementatie</span></a></li>
                        <li class="<?php if (is_page('cloud')) { echo "current_page_item"; }?>"><a href="/cloud" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-11.jpg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-11.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Cloud</span></a></li>
                        <li class="<?php if (is_page('webhosting-en-hosting')) { echo "current_page_item"; }?>"><a href="/webhosting-en-hosting" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-8.jpg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-8.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Webhosting / Hosting</span></a></li>
                        <li class="<?php if (is_page('unit4-multivers')) { echo "current_page_item"; }?>"><a href="/unit4-multivers" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-2.jpg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-2.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Unit4 Multivers</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>      
            </div>              
            </div>
            </div>
```

Anyone got any ideas what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hover the element, you set the background to the image related to the hovered element.

When you exit the hover, you don't set the image back to its pre-hover state.

EDIT: adding code sample, untested but it should give you the idea:

```
var imgsrc = '';
$('ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').hover(function(){
 imgsrc = $('.pikachoose').css('background-image');
  $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
  $('.pikachoose').css({ 'background-image' : 'url('+$(this).attr('src')+')' });
 }, function(){
  $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
  $('.pikachoose').css({ 'background-image' : 'url('+imgsrc+')' });
 });
```

Comment: I understand that theory. Could you maybe show me a sample code of how i could do this?

Comment: Ah i get this one but the problem is i can't put a hardcoded image link as hover out image because every page has a different background image. Also if i do this, my hover function gets removed somehow? Any ideas for this?

Comment: I checked the code on your site and you're missing `var imgsrc = '';` from the top.

Comment: Thanks I added it in the site but i can't hardcode the image link at `var imgsrc = '';`. It has a different background image on every page. Any suggestions on how to solve this ?

Comment: with the line `var imgsrc=''`, we're just initialising the variable.  It gets set before the hover to the background image that was previously chosen (see line 3 in the code in my answer).

Comment: Hm, not working.. it still does the same thing. I wonder why it won't turn back :( Any more ideas maybe?

Comment: Casii, please double check.  I compared the code on your site with mine and it is not the same. Where I have `'background-image' : 'url('+imgsrc+')'`, you have `'background-image': imgsrc`

Comment: Dear Phil, I changed the code to match what I needed. it's working well now, thanks for your help.